# Integral of product of functions $ \int_a^b fg =0 $ for all $g$ satisfying a condition

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

It's quite trivial to prove that $$ \int_a^b f(t)g(t)dt=0 , \forall g:\mathbb R\to [a,b] \space \space (1) $$
means that $f=0$. What i'm interested in is the following problem: suppose that  $(1)$ doesn't hold for all $g$, but for all $g:\mathbb R\to [a,b]$ that satisfy a certain condition. Specifically we have the following-it doesn't come from nowhere, it's physics related (kinda):

Let $$\vec N:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n , \space \vec h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n $$
We define the inner product $\bullet$ in $\mathbb R^n$ in the obvious way.
Now suppose all the functions $\vec x:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $\vec h(t) \bullet \vec x(t) =0$. $$ X= \{\vec x:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n |\vec h(t) \bullet \vec x(t) =0, \forall t\in [a,b] \}  $$

For some $a,b \in R$. Suppose now that $$ \int_a^b \vec x(t) \bullet \vec N(t) dt =0, \space \forall x \in X $$
What can we then say about $\vec N $? What I'd like to show is that $\vec N$ is parallel to $\vec h$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ (I don't know if it's true though). In the physics-case of the problem  $\vec x$ are actually virtual displacements $δ \vec x$, but I'm not sure it matters. Hope all makes sense and that no information about the physics problem is needed. Anyhow:

You can read the post if you'd like, but I dont think it's necessary https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/334029/deriving-the-lagrangian-in-constraint-motion-where-do-multipliers-come-from

Answer (score 1):

Assume that all functions involved are in $L^2 = L^2((a,b), \mathbb{R}^n)$, and that $h\neq 0$.
Then, using the Hilbert structure of $L^2$, you have that $X = h^\perp$ (the subspace of functions orthogonals to $h$).

Then your condition says that $(N,x) = 0$ for every $x\in h^\perp$, i.e. $N \in (h^\perp)^\perp = \text{span}(h)$. This means that there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $N = \lambda h$.

Comment: The inner product of $L^2 ( (a,b), R^n)$ is defined as the integral of the $R^n$-inner product of the two functions from a to b? Thus meaning that since $h \bullet x =0$ then their integral, i.e the inner product in $L^2$ is 0?

Comment: Yes, it is: $(h, x) := \int_a^b h(t) \cdot x(t)\, dt$.

Comment: Then $X$ is not $h^{ \bot }$, it's a subset of it, right? If $h \bullet x = 0 $ then of course $\int h \bullet x =0$, but it's not a necessity.